# Finding upper bound of tail of converging series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've just started my bachelor's degree in maths and we have started covering infinite series. An exercise that I have to complete is finding the upper bound of the tail of the series of reciprocals of square of natural numbers.

I know that an infinite series can be split up into a partial sum and a 'tail'/remainder. So, for the series of reciprocals of square of natural numbers, this would be represented as:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\frac{1}{n^2}} = \sum_{n=1}^{N} {\frac{1}{n^2}} + \sum_{n = N + 1}^{\infty} {\frac{1}{n^2}}$$

Note: the infinite series above converges to $$\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$
I'm asked to find an upper bound for the tail. How does one go about doing this? Do I first inspect the smallest possible value of the partial sum and then subtract from the value that the series converges to? If yes, how would I find the upper bound of a tail of a series whose value I don't know?

I've been searching round on the internet for a while now, in addition to asking a tutor but I am none the wiser. Please help!

Plus: The exercise said to use Oresme's trick, i.e. using a series reciprocal powers of 2 $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {\frac{1}{2^k}}$$ I'm guessing that this is supposed to act as an upper bound?

I am rambling, but in short I would like to know, **how does one find the upper bound of the tail of an infinite series?**

Side note: My skills in mathematics are humble. Please over-explain.

Answer (score 2):

You could observe $1/n^2\le 1/(n(n-1))$. You could also observe that
$$\frac 1{n^2}\le\int_{n-1}^n\frac{dx}{x^2}$$
so that
$$\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}\le\int_N^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2}.$$

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand where the first part comes from. As for integrals, I know that indefinite integrals are essentially infinite sums, but I have not done any formal reading on the exact connection. Anyhow, thank you for your answer :)